# Unable to view text on OMG! Ubuntu! website in Firefox 7

Tags: 11.10, firefox, websites

I am unable to view any text on the [OMG! Ubuntu!](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk) website. I am using Firefox 7 on Oneiric. I also have all the latest updates installed. I am using NoScript, if that matters. As you can see from the post, I have allowed all the necessary domains in NoScript. I even tried to view the page after temporarily allowing all scripts on the page using NoScript. Still got the same problem. So, NoScript is not the culprit here.

I was able to view this website properly a few days back on Oneiric. One day, I suddenly started getting this problem.

[image: Firefox screenshot 1]
[image: Firefox screenshot 2]

List of extensions that I am using:

- Noscript
- Adblock Plus with Element Hiding Helper (for text ads)
- Down Them All
- Flagfox
- Flashblock
- Foxrunner
- Https Everywhere
- Personas
- Restartless Restart
- Tab Preview
- WOT

Comment: so what happens if you disable noscript?

Comment: Also, what happens if you press Ctrl+A on the page or use your mouse to highlight everything?  Can you also try viewing the page's source to see if the text of the article is there?

Comment: You may want to provide a list of all the extensions you are using in Firefox. I can't reproduce this on my Oneiric install.

Comment: You should try launching Firefox in safe mode (all extensions temporary disabled) with this command: firefox -safe-mode

Comment: So, today I started Firefox from the terminal. And just like that, I could see all the text on omgubuntu.com. So, I closed the terminal and started Firefox normally. And I could still see all the text. So, my problem is fixed. Weird though! Thanks to all those who posted comments! Also, all my extensions (including Noscript) are running and I can still see all the text.

Comment: maybe it was a temporary problem...

Comment: So, the problem is showing up again. @MizukiOshiro, I can still view the text in Gedit, but not in the browser.

Comment: @Pisu, I can view the text in safe-mode.

Comment: @rigved: Can you select any text on the page even if you can't see it?

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, yes, like I mentioned, I can select all the text, copy-paste it to Gedit and view it there. Currently, the problem is gone; as in I can view the text in Firefox. But it recurs randomly.

Comment: maybe you should try a different browser...use the report a problem feature in firefox.maybe mozilla corporation can fix it.

Comment: works for me in chromium and google chrome

Comment: Are you still experiencing this issue?

Comment: @jrg no, it is fixed now in 12.04 with latest firefox. i'll close this question then...

Comment: do **NOT install WOT**, it can/must be considered as malware!!! - https://thehackernews.com/2016/11/web-of-trust-addon.html